# Include Exceptions as DataMember for DataContractSerializer WCF C#

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I want to return an array of exceptions in the DataContract from the WCF but it is not working.

```
    [DataContract]
    public class ProcessResult
    {
        [DataMember]
        public ProcessStatus EndStatus { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Exception[] CaughtExceptionList { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string CowListXML { get; set; }

    }
```

When i make the WCF call i get this exception

```
The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

I commented out/ignored the exception list as a data-member and i was able to get results back perfectly.

Thanks!

Comment: Not all exceptions are serializable.  What is the client connecting to the WCF service?

Comment: for now im just testing it with a console app in c#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the [ExceptionDetail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.exceptiondetail.aspx) class is what you are looking for.

Comment: any idea how i would convert an exception to ExceptionDetail?